# Is there a Web Server plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Just like the title says, are there any plugins that integrate a web server with Eclipse for quicker/easier web development?

I'm mainly looking for PHP development that can be done WITHOUT installing XAMPP or any other server software separately. Ideally, it'd work like Visual Studio - hit "Run", a Web server instance is started up and your script(s) are run, that allow you to step through code without going to the North Pole first (ok, one trip to the North Pole to set everything up is acceptable).

Am I dreaming or have I just been looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely exists! It's called the [Eclipse Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) (WTP for short), and it's very powerful. Furthermore, it is bundled inside the [Eclipse PHP Developer Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) (PDT) distribution, which is probably what you want to be using.

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that. Although to be fair I see nothing on PDT home page about a built-in server. I guess it's implied

Comment: Hey, I've been trying to set it up for a couple of days now, but still can't find a way to have everything run from within Eclipse WITHOUT having to start apache (with php) separately. Are you sure there's a way to get this functionality from within Eclipse? If yes, can you point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: @MK_Dev, were you able to find your answer about start/stop apache server within eclipse ? I am also stuck at this point. please post your solution if you have one.

Comment: @tusar, that's a negative. I found myself developing in other languages due to better tool support. Try Python/Django in PyCharm - you'll be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to set up the run configuration. I can't seem to be able to start a server from within eclipse

Comment: Sadly I too find this answer far from complete and suspect Adrian misunderstood the questions somehow. A simple link to the WTP site hasn't been helpful it sees to @MK_dev, or tusar or Painless or me. Would be great to hear back from Adrian. Like MK_Dev I actually do most of my work with Django but have I PHP needs as well. Django provides a simple webserver for debugging. I wonder if Eclipse can provide one the way VS does?

Comment: A modicum of progress. I note that Eclipse apparently has a Built-In webserver: With PHP Development Tools installed, on the **Run** menu click **Run Configurations**. On the list is **PHP Built-in Server**. I can't seem to get one working but hey ... it's on the list. On another front PHP itself provides a built-in server, with `php -S localhost:8000` for example. And this one I can get working (view my PHP site in it), but can't use for debugging yet. It's a start.