# Running a PHP Server via Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, wamp, eclipse-pdt

I have been trying to research this for a while, but can't seem to get it right.

Is it possible to run a PHP server using Eclipse as a replacement for WAMP or XAMPP?

I tried downloading the PDT package, and running that, but when it run it, `http://localhost` is returning a 404 (in the browser inside Eclipse as well as outside).

I'm working in a very restricted ("All software installs must be on the approved vendor list") environment, and Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 is available to me.

Please let me know (a) if this is even possible to accomplish my goal, and if so, (b) how to set it up so it works?

**Update:**

I tried downloading [Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/galileor), and now when I open it, it gives me 2 warnings:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Implementation of project facet php.component could not be found. Functionality will be limited.    TestingSERVER       Unknown Faceted Project Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Implementation of project facet php.core.component could not be found. Functionality will be limited.   TestingSERVER       Unknown Faceted Project Problem

And when I run it, I still get a 404 on both the page that I'm running it on, and for `http://localhost` itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Web Server plugin for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494956/is-there-a-web-server-plugin-for-eclipse)

Comment: That question is simply asking is there one, and the answer is PDT.  My question is (if that exists) how to get that to run like WAMP or XAMPP.

Comment: Eclipse documentation.